# Creating sessions for different member types AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax

i have successfully created an AJAX login system, however I want to implement it to look to two tables for instance members and super members. I want to re-direct the users depending on the first character of their username. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once 'config.php';
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername = $_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword']; 
// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and print "true"
    echo "true";
     $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
      $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;

}
else {
    //return the error message
    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Wrong Username or Password</div>";
}
ob_end_flush();
```

?>

And this is how I start the session in the main login page

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["myusername"])) {
header("location:login_success.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Add a column "memberType" in your table then $_SESSION['memberType'] = $mymembertype, and finally compare with if and redirect !

Comment: @user2196728 Thanks, that totally makes sense but I'm unsure of how to apply it, have you any idea how I could apply this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column "memberType" in your users table, then set $_SESSION['myMemberType'] = $mymembertype, and finally compare with "if" statement and redirect !
Something like this :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["myusername"]) && isset($_SESSION["myMemberType"])) {
  if($_SESSION["myMemberType"] == "members") {
      header("location:login_success_member.php");
  }
  if($_SESSION["myMemberType"] == "super members") {
      header("location:login_success_supermember.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems as though the AJAX is being posted within another file and is still picking up the login success page. I'm unsure of how to implement the code to allow the two functions to apply? Sorry if this seems like a silly question

Comment: I guess you are not fetching the result of your select statement :
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
Then
$_SESSION["myMemberType"] = $row['myMemberType'];

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table called UserTypes with id and privilege then add a column to users something like user_type_id which tracks the privilege level of users. then based on user_type _id you can redirect people to the correct page. google foreign keys for more info